# Convert IEEE float hex to decimal?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, ieee-754

IF I have a IEEE float hex 42F6E979, how do I convert it to decimal? I believe the decimal representation is = 123.456001

Comment: What assembly language and architecture?

Comment: do you mean ascii?  how does one convert from binary float to human readable ascii?

Answer (score 4):

(Most) assembly language doesn't really enforce types very strongly, so you can just initialize a location with that value, and then treat/use it as a float. The easiest way to convert is usually something like:

```
.data

myfloat dd 042F6E979H
mydec   db 10 dup(?)

.code

mov ebx, offset mydec    
fld myfloat
fbstp [ebx]
```

This actually produces binary coded decimal, so you have to split each byte into two digits for display. Of course, this is for x86 -- most other architectures make the job a tad more difficult. For example, on PowerPC, you have `fctiw`, which just converts to an integer (on the same general order as the x86 `fist`). To use it, you'd normally multiply by some multiple of 10 to get the number of decimal places you want, then convert to integer, and put a decimal point in the right place in the result. It can get a bit ugly when/if 1) you're close to the limits of the range for a floating point number, or 2) you want more precision than you can represent in a single integer.

Answer (score 3):

While you're testing out your own code, you can use [this online tool](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) to check your answer. FYI, you are correct in that the decimal is 123.45...

Wikipedia has a [useful article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) as well.

Answer (score 1):

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format#Converting_from_single_precision_binary_to_decimal) or call the library routine that probably already exists in your environment. It's a wheel often re-invented

Answer (score 0):

I'll do this in C, because you haven't provided a language.

```
char hex[];
int *ptr;
for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
{
   &ptr += toNumber(hex[i]) << (i * 4);
}

float *value = (float*)ptr;
```

I'll leave it up to the OP to write the toNumber function.

Comment: What the heck is `&ptr += ...` supposed to do?  The address-of operator doesn't give you an lvalue.  Do you mean something like `*(ptr++) = something`?  How is `ptr` initialized?