# intVal3 TBYTE 1234 -- invalid TBYTE variable declaration gone unnoticed by assembler

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I'm currently learning assembly programming by following Kip Irvine's "assembly language x86 programming" book.

In the book, the author states

> MASM uses the TBYTE directive to declare packed BCD variables.
>   Constant initializers must be in hexadecimal because the assembler
>   does not automatically translate decimal initializers to BCD. The
>   following two examples demonstrate both valid and invalid ways of
>   representing decimal -1234:
>
> ```
> intVal TBYTE 80000000000000001234h ; valid
> intVal TBYTE -1234 ; invalid
> ```
>
> The reason the second example is invalid
>   is that MASM encodes the constant as a binary integer rather than a
>   packed BCD integer.

I understand that the MASM assembler can't translate decimal integer to BCD. But I had come up with the following code that compiled just fine (notice that `intVal3 TBYTE 1234` is suppose to be invalid, but it was compiled just like valid code)

```
.386
.MODEL FLAT, STDCALL
.STACK 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode: DWORD

.DATA
intVal1 TBYTE 800000000000001234h
intVal2 TBYTE -1234h
intVal3 TBYTE -1234      ; compiled despite being invalid

.CODE 
    main PROC 


invoke ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main
```

Why has the invalid code gone unnoticed by the assembler? Is this an error that can't be detected by assembler and require vigilance on the part of the programmer?

=============== **EDIT 1** =================

I have checked the listing file as suggested by @PaulH, here is a screenshot

[image]

Judging from the result in the listing file and from what @PaulH said, I have arrived at the following conclusion (not sure entirely correct though):

variable of type TBYTE will interpret simple store the binary value of arguments (whether it would be 80000000000000001234h, -1234h or -1234) into the variable. Because variable of type TBYTE is suppose to be used as BCD integer, therefore it is entirely upto the programmer to make sure variable of type TBYTE is used correct.

Comment: If the current radix is decimal TBYTE will interpret the argument as BCD.

Comment: @PaulH Thank you for the comment. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought the author said TBYTE is interpreted as BCD when the radix is hexadecimal (not decimal, like you have mentioned in your comment). lol I'm confused :(

Comment: Sorry by current I meant the **default** (ie no specifier on argument) radix (which is normally always 10 -- decimal -- unless you've changed it with the .radix directive).  So by default TBYTE will interpret an all decimal digits argument as BCD.  Take a look at the bytes generated in the assembly listing (/Fl) to verify this.

Comment: @PaulH thanks for helping out. I think I finally understand after looking through the listing file. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think all TBYTE does is indicate to the programmer that this particular variable is of type TBYTE and the value within should be interpreted as BCD. But there is nothing to stop the programmer (except eternal vigilance) from using the value in the wrong way

Comment: Whoops not BCD by default, sorry again!   TBYTE just says it's a 10-byte data type.  The interpretation of the argument is no different from another type, say WORD.  So you could have the same trouble with WORD if you left the h off the end of an argument you wished to be BCD.  The default (no qualifiers) radix **is** 10, so with no qualifiers TBYTE will interpret the argument as decimal.  Therefore the largest TBYTE you can have is 1208925819614629174706175 (2**80-1).  Add 1 to that and TBYTE will give "error A2071: initializer magnitude too large for specified size"

Comment: @PaulH thanks paul! I think the concept is starting to become clear to me. Thanks for helping out! Really appreciate it!

Comment: I don't think `TBYTE` has anything to do with BCD, it's simply 10-byte wide type, it's native for x87 FPU coprocessor (the internal precision during calculations unless set to lower precision mode is 80 bits). While BCD is encoding of numbers, and can be used also with `BYTE`, `WORD`, etc... In the end, it doesn't matter how you specify the memory content in the source (defining the 10 bytes with 10 `BYTE` constants has same result as defining them in one `TBYTE` constant), the code which operates upon that memory defines it's "meaning" (type).

Comment: @Ped7g: x87 can (slowly) load/store 80-bit BCD integers with FBLD and [`FBSTP m80bcd`](https://hjlebbink.github.io/x86doc/html/FBSTP.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The raison d'être of the `TBYTE` type is to have something that is the same width as the x87 FPU's internal registers, meaning that it can be used to *spill* the contents of one of those registers to memory *without losing any precision*.

Normally, when you save a floating-point value in memory, you represent it either as a single-precision (32-bit; `DWORD`) or double-precision (64-bit; `QWORD`) value. This is fine, except that it loses precision. If you want to spill a temporary intermediate value during a computation, then you often cannot afford to lose precision by truncating the value because that will affect the final result.

The name `TBYTE` just means that values of this type are 10 bytes wide—the same width as [is used internally for floating-point values on the x87](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#IEEE_754_extended_precision_formats). (By default, at least, assuming you haven't decreased the FPU's precision.)

So, `TBYTE` really has nothing inherently to do with binary-coded decimal (BCD). I have no idea what Kip Irvine is talking about there. You could certainly store a BCD value in a `TBYTE`, but you could just as well store a smaller BCD value in a `QWORD` or `DWORD`. As the name suggests, [BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) is just an encoding that allows you to store decimal digits in binary form.

The reason why

```
intVal3 TBYTE -1234
```

<strike>compiles</strike> assembles is because, to the assembler (MASM), all you've done is declare a 10-byte value initialized to `-1234`. It implicitly extends `-1234` to fill 10 bytes, resulting in the value `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFB2E`, as you see in the hex dump. Same thing for `-1234h`, except that the `h` means the value is interpreted as being in hexadecimal, rather than decimal.

Notice that this is basically the same thing that would happen if you did

```
myValue QWORD -1234
```

because the assembler is going to extend `-1234` to be 8 bytes long.

As Ped7g says in a comment, the thing to remember above all when programming in assembly language is:

> In the end, it doesn't matter how you specify the memory content in the source, … the code which operates upon that memory defines its "meaning" (type).

The assembler just stores bytes. With `TBYTE`, it stores 10 of them. With `QWORD`, it stores 8 of them. With `DWORD`, it stores 4 of them. You get the picture. How your code *interprets* these bytes is up to you, because you have to write that code.

---

Peter Cordes points out (see comments) that the x87 FPU does have instructions designed to load and store BCD values: [`FBLD`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_82.html) and [`FBSTP`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_83.html). These [can be used as a slow way to turn a binary integer into decimal digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892132/convert-ieee-float-hex-to-decimal/3892263#3892263).

Both of these instructions take `m80bcd` values as their sole operand, which is an 80-bit BCD value that would be the same length as a `TYBTE`. So, it is *possible* that Kip Irvine is talking about this use for `TBYTE` values.

However, I don't believe that MASM implicitly converts `TBYTE` initializers to a BCD format, as that would be *very* inconvenient when you were using `TBYTE` to store an extended-precision floating-point value, as discussed above. With MASM or any other assembler, you are still on your own to represent the value assigned to a `TBYTE` appropriately as BCD or floating-point, whichever one you wanted.

And anyway, now that you've heard of `FBLD` and `FBSTP`, you can pretty much forget about them again. I don't think they were ever very commonly used, and they certainly don't get any use now. Even on older CPUs, like the original Pentium (P5) and Pentium II (P6), these instructions took ~150 clock cycles. On newer CPUs, they have gotten even slower (Skylake has a throughput of 1 `FBSTP` per 266 cycles). Therefore, even if you *did* want to work with 80-bit BCD values, you'd be better off writing out the necessary instructions yourself. (Ask a new question about that if you need help.)

Comment: @CaptainAmerica and Cody: probably Kip Irvine is talking about [`FBLD m80bcd`](https://hjlebbink.github.io/x86doc/html/FBLD.html) and [`FBSTP m80bcd`](https://hjlebbink.github.io/x86doc/html/FBSTP.html).  You can use it as a slow way to turn a binary integer into decimal digits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3892263/224132  (Skylake throughput of one `FBSTP` per 266 cycles, so multi-instruction loop will probably beat the micro-code loop if you avoid too many 64-bit `div` instructions for dividing by a compile-time-constant 10.)

Comment: IDK what different assemblers do for TBYTE constants.  It sounds like MASM doesn't do anything like what Irvine is talking about.

Comment: Wow, one per 266 cycles. No wonder I have never heard of or used this! In the quote, Irvine is talking specifically about MASM, so I doubt he's thinking of another assembler's behavior. If an assembler *did* turn all TBYTES into BCD format, though, that would be a major pain in the rear, since the type does have another much more common use, as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I have no idea what Kip is talking about.  Maybe an old version of MASM did something special?  Probably not worth worrying about it since hopefully nobody cares about BCD (except maybe for code-golf).  It might be a better design if there was a TBYTEBCD directive that converted a numeric constant to BCD.  And BTW, I checked and `fbstp` is still very slow even on much older CPUs (like ~150 clock on P5 Pentium and PII), so it was always slow, and in Nehalem and later Intel let it get even slower (since nobody uses it).